# Django-cms: Cannot delete pages in page-tree

Tags: python, django, django-cms

When I open the page tree and try to delete one of the pages, I encountered an error about `GET actions-menu 500`:

[image]

I wonder if this error is due to `bundle.admin.pagetree.min.js:1 [Deprecation] document.registerElement is deprecated and will be removed in M73, around March 2019. Please use window.customElements.define instead` in the console.

Here is my environment:

```
aldryn-apphooks-config     0.6.0
asgiref                    3.3.1
dj-database-url            0.5.0
Django                     3.1.7
django-admin-ip-restrictor 2.2.0
django-appdata             0.3.2
django-classy-tags         2.0.0
django-cms                 3.8.0
django-filer               2.0.2
django-formtools           2.2
django-ipware              3.0.2
django-js-asset            1.2.2
django-meta                2.0.0
django-mptt                0.11.0
django-parler              2.2
django-polymorphic         3.0.0
django-sekizai             2.0.0
django-sortedm2m           3.0.2
django-taggit              1.3.0
django-taggit-autosuggest  0.3.8
django-taggit-templatetags 0.2.5
django-templatetag-sugar   1.0
django-treebeard           4.4
djangocms-admin-style      2.0.2
djangocms-apphook-setup    0.4.1
djangocms-attributes-field 2.0.0
djangocms-blog             1.2.3
djangocms-bootstrap4       2.0.0
djangocms-file             3.0.0
djangocms-googlemap        2.0.0
djangocms-icon             2.0.0
djangocms-installer        2.0.0
djangocms-link             3.0.0
djangocms-picture          3.0.0
djangocms-snippet          3.0.0
djangocms-style            3.0.0
djangocms-text-ckeditor    4.0.0
djangocms-video            3.0.0
easy-thumbnails            2.7.1
html5lib                   1.1
lxml                       4.6.2
Pillow                     8.1.0
pip                        21.0.1
pkg-resources              0.0.0
pytz                       2021.1
setuptools                 44.0.0
six                        1.15.0
sqlparse                   0.4.1
tzlocal                    2.1
Unidecode                  1.1.2
webencodings               0.5.1
```

Beside this, I have another problem: [Djangocms: menu navigation error but it returned normal after zooming in······](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66850042/djangocms-menu-navigation-error-but-it-returned-normal-after-zooming-in)

Thank you for your help!!!!

Comment: did you update your static files and restarted your server?: `./manage.py collectstatic --noinput --clear`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried it but the same problem occured again....

Comment: What's the actual cause of the 500 error though? You should include the full traceback from your console to show the python error. The javascript deprecation message isn't the cause of the 500.